# Navigating arguments with AUCTeX

Tags: emacs, auctex

Is there a key combination to move the insertion point backward and forward through arguments using AUCTeX? For example, where "|" is my insertion point:

```
\frac{|}{}
```

Then I would want a command to move it:

```
\frac{}{|}
```

And perhaps another command to move it back:

```
\frac{|}{}
```

And another to move it out:

```
\frac{}{}|
```

Comment: [yasnippet](https://github.com/capitaomorte/yasnippet) does this sort of thing very well. Somebody has already written quite a few snippets for LaTeX, such as [this one](https://github.com/songqiang/yasnippets/blob/master/latex-mode/frac.yasnippet) for `\frac{}`. yasnippet can be used in other modes and languages as well as in TeX.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To move between empty groups I use these functions (can be improved of course):

```lisp
(defun mg-TeX-forward-group ()
  "Move to the next empty group."
  (interactive)
  (let ((group (save-excursion (search-forward-regexp "{[^}]*}" nil t))))
    (when group
      (set-mark (point))
      (deactivate-mark)
      (goto-char group)
      (backward-char 1))))
(eval-after-load "tex"
  '(define-key TeX-mode-map [M-right] 'mg-TeX-forward-group))
(defun mg-TeX-backward-group ()
  "Move to the previous empty group."
  (interactive)
  (let ((group (save-excursion (search-backward-regexp "{[^}]*}" nil t))))
    (when group
      (set-mark (point))
      (deactivate-mark)
      (goto-char group)
      (forward-char 1))))
(eval-after-load "tex"
  '(define-key TeX-mode-map [M-left] 'mg-TeX-backward-group))
```

Comment: Changing `search-forward "{}"` to `search-forward-regexp "{[^}]*}"` and `search-backward "{}"` to `search-backward-regexp "{[^}]*}"` is more what I was looking for.

Comment: @Geremia Your change has been approved, but you need to then change what the OP wrote about moving `between empty groups`.  The change you made will pick up non-empty groups too.

Comment: @A.Ellett That's fine.

Comment: Upon starting Emacs, I get this strange error when putting your code in my ~/.emacs file: ``Symbol's value as variable is void: TeX-mode-map``.

Comment: @Geremia I keep forgetting to wrap an `eval-after-load` around `define-key`s.  I'll update my answer.

Comment: @giordano I still get the same error…

Comment: @Geremia usually I test the code I provide, indeed the `mg-TeX-*-group` are tested, actually I use them.  The only parts of the code that haven't been tested were the `define-key`s, sorry.  There was a missing apostrophe to quote the `define-key`s.  Now they should work, tested `;-)`.

Comment: @giordano Ah, yes, I thought there should be one there… thanks. It works now for me, too. ☺